# MS Office 2010 Default setting for all users and remove update popup

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I *need* to use MS Office 2010 on Windows and upgrading to a newer version of Office is not a option.

I have a administrator account on Windows with MS Office installed, but every time a new user account it created it requires to put the default "User Name", "User Initials" and the what type of update that that user wants. This last one it the worse, because this should be a question only for administrators, not for the normal or invited user.

So, can anyone help me how to make this default to all users?

I have tried change the regedit so, but it does not work:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo]
"Company"="Company Name"
"UserName"=""
"UserInitials"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\General]
"ShownFirstRunOptin"=dword:00000001
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can't help you with your question, but I am very curious why you absolutely NEED to use Office 2010?

Comment: It's a moot point really, as there will never *be* any updates to Office 2010. It's End of Life.

Comment: I know that Office 2010 it old and not supported anymore. More, I personal wouldn't even use Office, but LibreOffice, but that is not the point. It need to put in a old system, it is a requirement not a option.

Comment: So, what does it matter what type of update the user wants?

Comment: That Update question is not necessary to the user, and especially not every time a user is created or temporary users. But I already found the answer to my question is using GPO and Administrative templates. I will answer my own question.

Comment: That Update question is not necessary to the user, and especially not every time a user is created or temporary users. But I already found the answer to my question is using GPO and Administrative templates. I will answer my own question. – user38561 - Jan 9 at 13:56 ••• Agreed. Well done, mate.

Comment: "Can't help you with your question, but I am very curious why you absolutely NEED to use Office 2010?" – MiG - Jan 7 at 20:17 ••• Yours is a preferential question only. Office 2010 fits a need, and is quite adequate for independent thinkers and hobbyist techies. Respect, MiG... с уважением

Comment: "It's a moot point really, as there will never be any updates to Office 2010. It's End of Life." – Tetsujin ••• And a 70 years old fit geezer can't get health insurance either, yes? And so... what to do with them...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using GPO and Office Administrative templates.

1. Download [Office 2010 Administrative Template files (ADM, ADMX/ADML) and Office Customization Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18968).
2. Unpack the corresponding Office Version (32bits or 64bits).
3. For local administration, copy the files ADMX from the unpacked folder "ADMX" to the folder `%systemroot%**\PolicyDefinitions` and the files ADML to the folder `%systemroot%**\PolicyDefinitions\<ll-cc>` (your language and country, example "en-uk" or "pt-pt").
4. Open `gpedit.msc`
5. In `User Configuration > Administrative > Microsoft 2010 > Privacy > Trust Center > Disable Opt-in Wizard on first time`, enable this option and the Update question will not appear every time a new user account opens an Office App from the first time.

Other resources: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2010/cc179081(v=office.14)